# Zend Framework: Query

Tags: zend-framework

How to do this query in Zend:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE statistic SET impressions = impressions+1 WHERE user_ip = 'my_ip'");
```

I try this:

```
$this->update(array('impressions' => 'impressions' + 1), array('user_ip = ?' => 'my_ip'));
```

But impressions aways are 1.

**That is true query:**

```
$this->update(array('impressions' => new Zend_DB_Expr('impressions + 1')), array('user_ip = ?' => 'my_ip'));
```

Comment: Put you solution into an answer and accept it, so someone else may profit from it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to add a number to a string in PHP. What gets sent to the database is just the number. You probably want this instead:

```
'impressions' => 'impressions + 1'
```

Comment: Now impressions in db is aways 0